4-BiT-Mode LCD doesn't show anything
Recently, I was making a driver for a 2*16 LCD to interface with "Atmega32", which works in 8-bit and 4-bit modes.
The 8-bit works fine but the 4-bit doesn't show any text >:(.
I am using protus for simulating.
main.c:-
#include "LCD.h"
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

int main(void)
{
    /* Configuration */
    LCD_Init();
    
    /* Code */
    char *ch = "Hello World";
    LCD_SendString(ch);
    
}

LCD.h:-
#include "LCD.h"

void LCD_Init(void)
{
    DIO_set_port_direction(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, (1<<E) | (1<<W) | (1<<RS));

#if (LCD_Bit_Mode == 8)
    DIO_set_port_direction(LCD_Data_Dir_ID, 0xFF);
    LCD_SendCommand(Eight_Bit_Two_Line_Mode);
#elif (LCD_Bit_Mode == 4)
    DIO_setPINDir(LCD_Data_Dir_ID, LCD_Data_Out3_ID, 1);
    DIO_setPINDir(LCD_Data_Dir_ID, LCD_Data_Out2_ID, 1);
    DIO_setPINDir(LCD_Data_Dir_ID, LCD_Data_Out1_ID, 1);
    DIO_setPINDir(LCD_Data_Dir_ID, LCD_Data_Out0_ID, 1);
    LCD_SendCommand(Four_Bit_Two_Line_Mode_INTI1);
    LCD_SendCommand(Four_Bit_Two_Line_Mode_INTI2);
    LCD_SendCommand(Four_Bit_Two_Line_Mode);
#endif

    LCD_SendCommand(CURSOR_OFF);
    LCD_SendCommand(CLEAR_COMMAND);
    
}

void LCD_SendCommand(uint8 data)
{
#if (LCD_Bit_Mode == 8)
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, RS, 0);          // 1
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, W, 0);   
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 2
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 1);           // 3
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 4
    DIO_write_port(LCD_Data_Dir_ID, data);      // 5
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 6
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 0);           // 7
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 8
    
#elif (LCD_Bit_Mode == 4)
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, RS, 0);          // 1
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, W, 0);
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 2
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 1);           // 3
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 4
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out3_ID,GET_BIT(data, 7));   // 5
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out2_ID,GET_BIT(data, 6));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out1_ID,GET_BIT(data, 5));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out0_ID,GET_BIT(data, 4));
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 6
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 0);           // 7
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 8
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 1);           // 9
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 10
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out3_ID,GET_BIT(data, 3));   // 11
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out2_ID,GET_BIT(data, 2));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out1_ID,GET_BIT(data, 1));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out0_ID,GET_BIT(data, 0));
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 12
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 0);           // 13
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 14

#endif

}

void LCD_SendCharacter(uint8 data)
{
#if (LCD_Bit_Mode == 8)
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, RS, 1);          // 1
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, W, 0);
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 2
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 1);           // 3
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 4
    DIO_write_port(LCD_Data_Dir_ID, data);      // 5
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 6
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 0);           // 7
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 8
#elif (LCD_Bit_Mode == 4)
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, RS, 1);          // 1
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, W, 0);
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 2
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 1);           // 3
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 4
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out3_ID,GET_BIT(data, 7));   // 5
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out2_ID,GET_BIT(data, 6));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out1_ID,GET_BIT(data, 5));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out0_ID,GET_BIT(data, 4));
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 6
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 0);           // 7
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 8
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 1);           // 9
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 10
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out3_ID,GET_BIT(data, 3));   // 11
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out2_ID,GET_BIT(data, 2));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out1_ID,GET_BIT(data, 1));
    DIO_write(LCD_Data_Dir_ID,LCD_Data_Out0_ID,GET_BIT(data, 0));
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 12
    DIO_write(LCD_Ctrl_Dir_ID, E, 0);           // 13
    _delay_ms(1);                               // 14

#endif

}

void LCD_SendString(uint8 *str)
{
    for(;*str != '\0';str++)
        LCD_SendCharacter(*str);
    
}

void LCD_MoveCursor(uint8 row, uint8 col)
{
    uint8 address;
    switch (row)
    {
        case 0:
            address = col;
            break;
        case 1:
            address = col + 0x40;
            break;
        case 2:
            address = col + 0x10;
            break;
        case 3:
            address = col + 0x50;
            break;
    }
    
    LCD_SendCommand(address | SET_CURSOR_LOCATION);
    
}

void LCD_SendStringRowCol(uint8 row, uint8 col, uint8 *str)
{
    LCD_MoveCursor(row,col);
    LCD_SendString(str);
    
}

void LCD_IntegerToString(uint16 data)
{
    uint8 BUFF[16];
    itoa(data,BUFF,10);
    LCD_SendString(BUFF);
    
}

void LCD_ClearScreen()
{
    LCD_SendCommand(CLEAR_COMMAND);
    
}

Don't worry about DIO functions which setting pins and ports, they work fine with 8-bit mode.
Here is a picture for the end of the simulation, when I run it I see the data bus transferring the data correctly but nothing showing up!!!!!!!!
I doubted the initializing, but I checked it a million but nothing, I tried to make separate initializing following this Page.
I checked the code sequences of sending commands and characters a million times.
I checked connections and other codes.

I don't know anything about this area but suggest you revised your question with [mre] and start testing bottom up.  Does the hardware work?  Is it wired up correctly?  Is the data you send making it to the DUT?

Not related to your problem, but it is really bad practice to put your functions into a header. A header should only include declarations. If you include the header in multiple C files, you will end up with multiple definitions which is an error. You should put the function definitions into a separate C file.

You need to use DB4 to DB7, not DB0 to DB3.
